# Why does `toml.load(f)` fail with this file under Windows (but not on Linux)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, character-encoding, toml

I have a [TOML](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/a6643b03a6e11026b38e1276365beb09) file which I want to process with [this script](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/0cf6187332bc8b2284c1101650f0a47e).

This used to work fine under Linux. Under Windows (`Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:23:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`) I get the following error:

```
Need to process 1 file(s)
Processing file test01.toml (1 of 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py/process.py", line 27, in <module>
    add_text_fragment(input_dir + "/" + file)
  File "<string>", line 10, in add_text_fragment
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\toml\decoder.py", line 134, in lo
ad
    return loads(f.read(), _dict, decoder)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 985: char
acter maps to <undefined>
```

I assume that the error happens somewhere here:

```
f = open(toml_file_name, "r")
pt = toml.load(f)
f.close()
```

According to NotePad++, the [file](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/a6643b03a6e11026b38e1276365beb09)  in question has UTF-8 encoding.

How can I fix it?

**Terms of the bounty**

I will award this bounty to a person who shows me how to make sure that the script [process.py](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/54d3d5c7ab7826d1bf4a1f33c49bbe46) correctly processes the [input file](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/a6643b03a6e11026b38e1276365beb09), i. e. the execution gets past the comment starting with `If at this point pt` in [addTextFragment.py](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/0cf6187332bc8b2284c1101650f0a47e)

```
def add_text_fragment(toml_file_name):
    f = open(toml_file_name, "r")
    pt = toml.load(f)
    f.close()

    # If at this point pt contains dthe data of the input file,
    # then you have attained the goal.
    if (pt["type"] == "TA"):
```

and the variable `pt` contains the data from the [input file](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/a6643b03a6e11026b38e1276365beb09).

Your solution must work under Windows 10, Python 3.7.6 `(default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`.

Note: `process.py` executes `addTextFragment.py` for all files in a particular directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace this line:

```
f = open(toml_file_name, "r")
```

with:

```
f = open(toml_file_name, "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

As you can see in the error message, Python is trying to read the file with the default system encoding for files - if the file contains any
non-ASCII chars and was working in Linux, it means it has a different encoding - and the default encoding for all non-Windows world is utf-8 .

Answer (score 1):

it seems like toml was trying to decode your data but failed.
As you said the data in your toml file is UTF-8 encoded. I'd decode it manually to avoid possible charset detecting in toml lib.

```
with open(toml_file_name, 'rb') as f:
    pt = toml.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```